Are there any windows 11 settings for stacked toolbar icons which will shortcut me back to the last opened when I click on them?
I like that the taskbar stacks up multiple windows, but I'd like to save a click when I have two explorer folders open, for example.

A suggestion: Rather than asking for a tool or setting that does X, ask how to accomplish X or how to solve problem Y. Also, tell us what you've tried and summarize any research you've done and what you've learned doing it. This will help make your question better and better able to be answered here.
